# Insert data in middle of a file

Tags: java, file-io, nio

I have a very large file which needs to be edited. I need to insert data anywhere in the file. It is using Java NIO. I found two options,

1. Keep the entire file in-memory and insert the data there. And flush at the end.

   - this is not possible in my case since the file size is very large (may be in GB)
2. Say I need to insert at position=n and the file size=L. Then first I need to copy the existing data (L-n), then insert my content and then write back the copied text

   - this is also not possible as this will increase I/O over the hue file

Can FileChannel really append data in middle and automaically shift the consecutive bytes internally? (I don't think so)

However, Is there any opinion from your side regarding the actual problem? Any sort of option is well-come, but better to have it in Java.

Comment: you may want to try [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html)

Comment: @Dongqing : I have tried with that only. But it seems that it does not append in middle and shift the consecutive bytes. It always overwrite. So the existing data at that position is gone.

Comment: Discussed with teammate and didn't come to a solution, what's the original problem? May we redesign the file structure, for example, we use an index file to index the blocks of the real data file, so we can modify small index file to maintain blocks order while always append real data after the big data file.

Comment: We can not change the file format since the format is defined by the client. However, indexing could be a good option only if we can insert an entire chunk (few lines together) at once in the output file without iterating the source line by line.